# Iterate all columns Pandas Dataframe and compare alternate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 95 columns and starting from 4th column, I want to compare 4th column with 5th column and insert result as 6th column and 7th and 8th column and insert data in 8th column and do it till the end in a loop. How to achieve this in pandas?

```
Ex of manual compare. 
df['col_compare'] = np.where(df['payment_dt'] == df['payment_dt_x'], 'no change', 'changed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 10):  # fill the DataFrame
    df['Column' + str(i)] = [random.randint(1, 2) for x in range(0, 10)]
for i in range(0, len(df.columns) - 2, 3):
    df.iloc[:, i + 2] = np.where(df.iloc[:, i] == df.iloc[:, i + 1], 'no change', 'changed')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2    Column3  Column4  ...    Column6 Column7  Column8    Column9
0        2        2  no change        1  ...  no change       1        1  no change
1        1        2    changed        2  ...  no change       2        1    changed
2        1        2    changed        1  ...  no change       1        1  no change
3        2        2  no change        2  ...    changed       1        1  no change
4        1        1  no change        2  ...    changed       2        2  no change
5        2        1    changed        2  ...  no change       2        2  no change
6        2        1    changed        2  ...  no change       2        1    changed
7        2        2  no change        2  ...  no change       1        1  no change
8        2        1    changed        1  ...    changed       2        2  no change
9        2        2  no change        2  ...  no change       1        1  no change

[10 rows x 9 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```